# Difference between paint() and paintcomponent()?

Tags: java, swing, paint, paintcomponent

I have tried tutorials on this but I still don't quite understand it. Basically my question is which method is better and why? Should I use `paint` or `paintComponent`?

Please try to keep the answer simple, thanks.

Comment: See also [*Painting in AWT and Swing*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Quoting from documentation of `paint()` method

> This method actually delegates the work of painting to three protected methods: paintComponent, paintBorder, and paintChildren.
>      ...
>   A subclass that just wants to specialize the UI (look and feel) delegate's paint method should just override paintComponent.

It looks like the `paint()` method actually draws the component, including the border and children. If you only want to customize the component's appearance excluding the border and children, you use `paintComponent()`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paint(java.awt.Graphics)

Comment: While correct, it would be prudent to link to a more to update version of the JavaDocs, just to highlight to developers potential changes to the API

Comment: I edited the link. thanks @MadProgrammer for reminding me about this

Comment: Still got a +1 for the answer regardless ;)

Answer (score 10):

Generally speaking, when painting in Swing, it is recommended to override `paintComponent`.

There are a number of reasons why, one is `paintComponent` is painted at the bottom layer, meaning you won't accidentally wiping out any components that were rendered during the paint process - this happens a lot to people who post here.

There are a, very, few times you might need to override `paint`, but I would always encourage you to try making it work with `paintComponent` first.

Check out

- [Performing custom painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) (+1 to trashgod)

Comment: I don't think it matters if you override paint() or paintComponent() from a double buffering point of view. See the double buffering section from the "Painting in AWT and Swing" article. Now if you happen to override paint() at a frame level (which I never recommend) and forget about invoking super.paint() then you can get into some trouble.

Comment: @camickr Ah yes, you're right, that's the argument for not overriding top level containers :P