# Paint in Swing not working

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint, repaint

Why does this not work?  It shows me the GUI but not the paint.  How would I change this into two classes?

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class runpaintgui extends JFrame{    

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(5000,2000);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setTitle("game");
        frame.setVisible(true);    
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawString("adsf",40,45);
        g.draw3DRect(50, 30, 600, 700, true);   

        repaint();
    }    
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "How would I change this into two classes?"

Comment: never to call repaint(); inside paint()/paintComponent(), because can creating endless loop

Comment: Try to extends your panel and override paintComponent() method as the [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103553/difference-between-paint-and-paintcomponent) say.

Comment: *"frame.setSize(5000,2000);"*  You really have a 10 mega pixel display?  What is it, the Jumbotron?

Comment: "***runpaintgui***"; It's a good habit to use some name rules.  You can refer to http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a generic `JFrame` in this line:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

What you want to probably do is:

```
JFrame frame = new runpaintgui();
```

Then your `paint()` method *will* be called.

Answer (score 5):

You have to instantiate your class and not the `JFrame` class.

change:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

to

```
runpaintgui frame = new runpaintgui();
```

Then your `paint()` method *will* be called.

And do not call `repaint()` in `paint`. Because `repaint()` calls `paint`.