# Do we have to import something to use draw()?

Tags: java, draw

I am trying to draw some rectangles in java using eclipse and calling the `draw()` method gives me an error. Is there something I am missing here?

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class UsingRectangle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle box1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 30);

        //error "The method draw() is undefined for the type Rectangle"
        box1.draw();
    }
}
```

Any help would be more than appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: @BlueIce It's in the question - "The method draw() is undefined for the type Rectangle"

Comment: Your error is saying that the class Rectangle doesn't have that method. Out of curiosity, where did you think that rectangle was going to appear? You should look at the [Swing Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) if you want to start doing graphical things.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to draw? Is it a graphic? What made you think that Rectangle has that method? Did you see it somewhere? It's possible it was a custom class. If you want to draw a graphics. See [How to do Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). Also see [Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) which does have a `draw(Shape)` method. Please elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish. Your code example doesn't really say much

Comment: Just as a side note, Eclipse will underline any unknown references and will suggest possible solutions, including any import statements of standard Java library classes that would resolve the error.

Comment: @peeskillet I am trying to draw a rectangle. Yes, a graphic. I was working using blueJ and the snippet just worked fine. Now that I am using eclipse, most of my code is not working. Thank you for the links you have provided.

Comment: @Angelo yep, that's because this wasn't a case of simply not importing the necessary class, so you know it is a deeper problem. See MadProgrammer's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Start by having a read through:

- [JavaDocs for `Rectangle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html)
- [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

`Rectangle` is a representation of a shape, in of itself, it has no concept of how to paint, but can be painted through the appropriate APIs

[image: Rectangle]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class PaintRectangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PaintRectangle();
    }

    public PaintRectangle() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Rectangle box1;

        public TestPane() {
            box1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 30);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.fill(box1);
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2d.draw(box1);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That may be one of the most boring example images I've seen in a while ;-D

Comment: @peeskillet I'll make it bounce and flash later ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you for this, very helpful. I might be wrong but I think BlueJ has a costumed draw(), and that is what confused me with all this.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you draw rectangles. Google a bit before you post questions :)

```
// Draw rectangles
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class Rectangles extends Applet {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect(10, 10, 60, 50);
        g.fillRect(100, 10, 60, 50);
        g.drawRoundRect(190, 10, 60, 50, 15, 15);
        g.fillRoundRect(70, 90, 140, 100, 30, 40);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Example taken from `Java The complete reference` by `Herbert Schildt`

Comment: Not the [dreaded Applet!!!](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/)

Comment: Consider using Swing over AWT, consider using `Graphics2D` over `Graphics`, consider calling `super.paint` and in fact, one would argue you shouldn't be overriding a `paint` of top level containers.  `Applet`s are inheriently difficult to manage and you consider using a `JPanel` (as the primary surface) and a `JFrame` to display it instead. Consider providing a more suitable answer before posting

Comment: Yep I know Swing should be used, but as the OP had imported `awt` so I used applets

Comment: `Rectangle` is simply a class within the AWT package, doesn't mean that the OP wants to use AWT

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for all that information. I haven't ever used Applet myself, so never knew about these things. I just read everywhere that Swing is better, so always ended up using Swing, and never bothered why it is so. Thanks

Comment: @kushpf The snippet I pasted above just works fine in blueJ. I was confused about why it was not working in eclipse. I tried  to find  how to use draw() but I could not find anything. Thank you for the reference you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

You want it to draw where? See your code you are using main which will output in console, and actually main without extending special class like `JFrame` (this is what you need because this is where you can draw ,this is a window in java)

see below code, for other way drawing your rectangle.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

class UsingRectangle extends JComponent {

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawRect (10, 10, 200, 200);  
  }
}

public class DrawRect {
  public static void main(String[] a) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
    window.getContentPane().add(new UsingRectangle());
    window.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

or using paintComponent

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class UsingRectangle extends JPanel {
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawRectangle (10, 10, 200, 200);  
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    });
    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.add(new UsingRectangle());
    frame.show();
  }
}
```

also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103553/difference-between-paint-and-paintcomponent) for what the difference of `paint` and `paintComponent` for future reference.

Comment: Favor `paintComponent` over `paint`, as this could produce paint artifacts and or affect other components which are management by the container...

Comment: @MadProgrammer ,thanks sir, answer editted for that.

Comment: What is `MyCanvas` and `NotHelloWorldPanel`?