# Drawing a shape on a JPanel which already uses the paint method

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel, paint, ellipse

Let's say I have two classes, the first extends JPanel and using Graphics draws a playing board on it. The second makes a JFrame and adds the panel to it.

You can imagine the frame looking something like this:
[image: sample JFrame]

I now want to add an ellipse to a specific rectangle on click. I understand that I would be using a two-dimensional array in order to get the position I wanted, but I don't understand how the ellipse itself would be drawn on to the existing panel since I used the `paint(Graphics g)` to draw the playing board.

Here is the code for drawing the board itself if you need it:

```
class MyBoard extends JPanel {
    private static int height = 6;
    private static int width = 7;
    private static int squareSize = 100;
    private int board[][] = new int[height][width];

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                g.drawRect(j * squareSize, i * squareSize, squareSize, squareSize);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: First off: You should never override `paint` but always `paintComponent`. Second: In the overriden code you should generally call `super.paint` (or `super.paintComponent` once you made the switch). Third: You could simply save the square you want to draw in (let's say x = 1, y = 0) and then draw the ellipse there after your two for-loops like `g.drawOval(x*squareSize + squareSize/4, y*squareSize + squareSize/4, squareSize/2, squareSize/2);`

Comment: @Ben Thanks! I switched to the `paintComponent` and added the `super` , but could you tell me what the difference is? They do the same thing right? Also lets say I wanted to create the ellipse on click. How would I go about that? Make an mouse listener and get the coordinates, but how would I then pass those x and y values to the `paintComponent` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First two things that you should remember: Never override `paint` but `paintComponent` and call `super.paintComponent` in there so that borders and everything works as expected. Regarding why this is the case, reference this question: [Difference between paint() and paintcomponent()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103553/difference-between-paint-and-paintcomponent)

---

Now to answer your question. Assuming you have an existing logic to determine in which square you want to draw your Ellipse (let's assume you have two `Integer`s `elX` and `elY` that are the column and row of your square) you can simply go and draw it after you have finished drawing the board itself.

Imagine sample code like this:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    // Draw the board
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            g.drawRect(j * squareSize, i * squareSize, squareSize, squareSize);
        }
    }

    // Draw the ellipse at the correct location using half the size of a normal square.
    g.drawOval(elX * squareSize + squareSize / 4, elY * squareSize + squareSize / 4, squareSize / 2 , squareSize / 2);
}
```

---

Now the final part of how to go about actually determining where to draw your ellipse.
A simple solution would be to add a `MouseListener` to your panel. And then in the `mouseClicked` method you calculate where you actually did click.

Could look like this:

```
this.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
{

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        int column = e.getX() / squareSize;
        int row = e.getY() / squareSize;

        board[column][row] = 1;
    }

    [...] // add the other methods to override

}
```

Then you slightly adapt your `paintComponent` method with something like this:

```
for (int column = 0; column < width; ++column)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < height; ++row)
    {
        if (board[column][row] == 1)
        {
            g.drawOval(column * squareSize + squareSize / 4, row * squareSize + squareSize / 4, squareSize / 2, squareSize / 2);
        }
    }
}
```

and now you draw an ellipse everywhere you click. You could also check if the clicked square already has `1` set as a value and reset it to `0` to have some toggle mechanism or increment it and draw different things based on the integer value... it's all up to you :)

Comment: Thanks! I also have a follow up question : how could I draw the ellipse on different squares when I pressed on them? I would use the mouse listener and get the x and y coordinates and then what would I do to pass them to the `paintComponent` ?

Comment: @SomeStudent I've updated the answer a bit. Also I just used the currently unused `board` 2D-Array for this. Obviously feel free to change this to single variables or just use another array.

Comment: Glad I could help.