# draw or paint a 2D array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, jframe, jpanel, paint

I am a beginner in java and appologies for any wrong terminology.

I am trying to create a simple 2D game just to learn more about how java works.

For now what I would want to know is how I would go about using a 2D array and drawing it. And maybe add a simple icon(player) you can move around with the arrowkeys.

Currently I have the following classes Keybarricade:

```
public class Keybarricade{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame obj = new JFrame();
    Playingfield playingfield = new Playingfield();

    obj.setBounds(0, 0, 900, 900);
    obj.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    obj.setResizable(false);
    obj.setVisible(true);
    obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    obj.add(playingfield);
}
```

and playingfield:

```
public class Playingfield extends JPanel{
private ImageIcon playerIcon;
private int [][] playinggrid = new int[10][10];
private int [] playerX = new int[10];
private int [] playerY = new int[10];

public Playingfield()
{

}

public void paint (Graphics g)
{
    //draw border for playingfield
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.drawRect(10, 10, 876, 646);

    //draw background for the playingfield
    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(11, 11, 875, 645);

    //draw player imageicon
    playerIcon = new ImageIcon("src/images/playerIcon.png");
    playerIcon.paintIcon(this, g, playerX[1], playerY[1] );

}
```

this gives the following window:[window I have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCH0f.png)

What I would want is to use the 2D array to draw/paint a 10x10 grid, something like this: [window I would like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWQHk.png)

But sadly I couldnt find a way to do this or I did but didnt understand it.
If someone could point me in the right dirrection that would be awsome!

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this in your paint function:

```
    int boxWidth = 30;
    int boxHeight = 30;

    for (int currentX = 0; 
            currentX < playinggrid.length * boxWidth;
            currentX += boxWidth) {
        for (int currentY = 0;
                currentY < playinggrid[0].length * boxHeight;
                currentY += boxHeight) {
            g.drawRect(currentX, currentY, boxWidth, boxHeight);
        }
    }
```

If you want to draw the icon in the middle of a cell you can do the following inside the two for loops:

```
    g.drawImage(playerIcon.getImage(),
                currentX + boxWidth/2 - playerIcon.getIconWidth()/2,
                currentY + boxHeight/2 - playerIcon.getIconHeight()/2,
                null);
```

BTW: I think it's better to override paintComponent instead of paint, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103553/difference-between-paint-and-paintcomponent)

Comment: Thanks! That did indeed create the grid I was looking for. 
Would you happen to know how I could go about placing a playericon in the center of the diffrent cells?