# Java on Eclipse won't show the JPanel even when I add it to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jpanel

These are the files. I have set JFrame to be visible, and have added JPanel to it, but still, the code only shows the window without anything in it.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.util.Collections;


public static void main(String[] args)
{

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(350, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("My Empty Window");
    frame.setVisible(true);

    DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel();
    
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

-------------DRAWINGPANEL FILE-------------------

```
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;

 public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

      public void painting(Graphics pen) {

         pen.drawRect(50, 50, 20, 20);
         pen.drawRect(100, 50, 40, 20);
         pen.drawOval(200,50,20,20);
         pen.drawOval(250, 50, 40, 20);
         pen.drawString("Square", 50, 90);
         pen.drawString("Rectangle", 100, 90);
         pen.drawString("Cirlce", 200, 90); 
         pen.drawString("Oval", 250, 90);
         pen.fillRect(50, 100, 20, 20);
         pen.fillRect(100, 100, 40, 20);
         pen.fillOval(250, 100, 20, 20);
         pen.fillOval(250, 100, 40, 20);
         pen.drawLine(50, 150, 300, 150);
         pen.drawArc(50, 150, 200, 100, 0, 180);
         pen.fillArc(100, 175, 200, 75, 90, 45);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the method in `DrawingPanel` from `painting` to `paint`, which will get called when run. `paint` is a method inherited from `JPanel`.

Edit: As mentioned by [NomadMaker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9732672/nomadmaker), use `paintComponent()` not `paint()` here. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103553/difference-between-paint-and-paintcomponent) for more information.

Comment: That was it! Thank you. My old textbook has it labeled "paintComponents" instead. Maybe they changed it to "paint" since 2011?

Comment: Looking at the [JPanel docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html), `paint` and `paintComponent` are still methods.

Comment: Just realized I used paintComponents as a plural instead of without the 's'.

Comment: You should override paintComponent() rather than paint().

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I get after making your code runnable, fixing your `JFrame` method calls and fixing your drawing `JPanel`.

[image: Image GUI]

Swing applications should always start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

You pack a `JFrame`.  You set the preferred size of your drawing `JPanel`.  This way, you know how big your drawing `JPanel` is, without worrying about the `JFrame` decorations.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DrawingPanelExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new DrawingPanelExample());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Empty Window");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel();
        frame.add(panel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public DrawingPanel() {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 300));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics pen) {
            super.paintComponent(pen);

            pen.drawRect(50, 50, 20, 20);
            pen.drawRect(100, 50, 40, 20);
            pen.drawOval(200, 50, 20, 20);
            pen.drawOval(250, 50, 40, 20);
            pen.drawString("Square", 50, 90);
            pen.drawString("Rectangle", 100, 90);
            pen.drawString("Cirlce", 200, 90);
            pen.drawString("Oval", 250, 90);
            pen.fillRect(50, 100, 20, 20);
            pen.fillRect(100, 100, 40, 20);
            pen.fillOval(250, 100, 20, 20);
            pen.fillOval(250, 100, 40, 20);
            pen.drawLine(50, 150, 300, 150);
            pen.drawArc(50, 150, 200, 100, 0, 180);
            pen.fillArc(100, 175, 200, 75, 90, 45);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override paintComponent like so:

```
...

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D pen = (Graphics2D) g;
...
}
```

Also some suggestions:

- You can extending `JComponent` instead of `JPanel` (It should work both ways)
- You can use `setSize` or `setPreferredSize` for your `panel` to fit it with your frame size.
- You can only use `setVisisble(true);` only once after all of the configurations of your frame.
- And add it to the center of the frame like so:

```
...
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(350, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("My Empty Window");

    DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimensions(350, 300));
    
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setVisible(true);
...
```

On a side note:

Adding a layout manager may not be necessary and you can also replace `setPreferredSize` with `setBounds` like so:

```
panel.setBounds(0, 0, 350, 300);

frame.add(panel);
```

Where 0s are x and y coordinates respectively.