# java jpanel center position in jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Whats the correct way to position a Jpanel in Jframe?
I have tried to use BorderLayout.CENTER as a second arg in jframe.add(jpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER). I have also tried to setBounds(20, 20, width, height) in jpanel object and setAlignmentX((width+50)/2). But none of these worked, each of the above was ignored so the jpanel was positioned in the upper left corner, overlapping the window panel. I havent found a working solution on stackOverflow.

I want the gameboard positioned in a center of a jframe.

```
public class MainBoard extends JFrame {

    public MainBoard(String title,int width, int height){
        setTitle(title);
        setSize(new Dimension(width+50, height+50));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        createBufferStrategy(2);
        GameBoard g = new GameBoard(width, height, getBufferStrategy());
        add(g);

    }

}
```

```
public class GameBoard extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    private final int WIDTH;
    private final int HEIGHT;
    private boolean inGame;
    private final BufferStrategy bs;
    private final int FRAME_DELAY = 50;
    private long cycleTime;

    public GameBoard(int width, int height, BufferStrategy bs) {
        addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
        setFocusable(true);
        setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        WIDTH = width;
        HEIGHT = height;
        this.bs = bs;
        gameInit();
    }
```

Comment: "Whats the correct way to position a Jpanel in Jframe?". There is no absolute correct way. there are different attempts, depending on what you want to achieve. A few of them, you have mentioned in your post. So what do you want to achieve, what you cant over a box layout?

Comment: *What's the correct way to position a JPanel in a JFrame?*  The correct way is to use [Swing layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).  Your question implies that you have multiple JPanels, but you only show one.  Centering one JPanel is trivial.  See this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65484190/java-on-eclipse-wont-show-the-jpanel-even-when-i-add-it-to-jframe/65485547#65485547) for the correct code to center one JPanel.

Comment: Ive edited the question. I want to position the GameBoard in a center of a jframe. Now the upper part of the GameBoard overlaps the window panel, any idea why?

Comment: Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem.